# Regex Pattern to Match Character Not Surrounded by Particular Characters

Tags: python, regex, calibre

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match a certain character only when it isn't immediately adjacent to a certain character. (For an eBook in Calibre)

Specifically, I want to match all `”` that aren't at the end of a sentence, which means they will be between regular characters, not an angle bracket or space. I thought `”[^<]` would work, but that selects both the quotation mark and the next character, not just the character itself. I'm also not sure how to do an OR to check for a space. I'm assuming it would be something like `”[^<]|[^ ]` but that's not right either.

Here's an example of what I would like to match:

Beside angle bracket:
`<p class="calibre1">“I”m tired!”</p>`

Beside space: `<p class="calibre1">“I”m tired!” he said</p>`

Only the quotation mark within `I”m` should be selected (and only the quotation mark itself)

I'm sorry if there's an obvious answer for this, but I've been reading over Python's regex documentation and I can't figure it out. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perhaps use a negative lookahead `(?! ... )` like that:

```
”(?!<)
```

This will match `”` unless it is followed by `<`.

To add the space...

```
”(?![< ])
```

That one will match `”` unless followed by `<` or space.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [negative-lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
regex = r '"(?!<|\s)'
```

`|` means "or"
`\s` means whitespace

You don't need to capture, since you know you're only matching a `"`.

Alternatively, you could use a character class instead of the or, ie: `[<\s]`.